# Create a rewrite rule based on querystring

Tags: .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting

I have many redirects in the .htaccess file.  Now, I need to create a rewrite rule for a URL based on it's querystring value..

```
http://www.mydomain.com/subdir/RentalDetails.aspx?RentalId=1072
```

any traffic to this url should go to...

```
http://www.mydomain.com/subdir/RentalDirectory.aspx
```

I have researched and found some good posts on the subject and came up with this..

```
#discontinued properties
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/RentalDetails\.aspx$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^RentalId=1072$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$      /subdir/RentalDirectory.aspx?                [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately, it is not working.  Could someone please help me to figure out where I have gone wrong?  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: By 'not working', do you mean that you aren't generating any redirect at all, or that the redirect is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that the RewriteCond is wrong: the uri shouldn't look like

```
^/RentalDetails\.aspx$
```

[Edited -- I finally managed to get to the actual docs, and found the query string was a red herring. However, I missed the '^' at the start of the string as well, which may be causing this]

Since the `^` at the start of the expression means "the string must start here", and the `$`at the end means "the string ends here", your regex is too restrictive, and won't match what you need it to.

From the apache docs, the `REQUEST_URI` variable excludes the query string, so that's not the issue. However, you are trying to match a url of `/subdir/RentalDetails.aspx` with a regex that has to start with the word `/RentalDetails`

Try something like

```
# No ^ at the start, this will match RentalDetails.aspx in any location
/RentalDetails\.aspx$
```

Or

```
# This will only match in the /subdir/ directory.
^/subdir/RentalDetails\.aspx$
```

Comment: Ahh, yes, that does make sense.  I should have caught that.  Unfortunately, neither of your suggestions work.

Comment: I checked the docs, and that wasn't correct (the query string is excluded from the request URI. I've updated the answer for you, with another thing to try

Comment: Thats it!  Thank you very much! I chose to use the more restrictive match including the subdir.